# Drawing a rectangle (or line, or bitmap) on the camera preview stream (.NET Compact Framework)

Tags: camera, compact-framework, overlay, directshow, directshow.net

I'm working on a .NET CF 2.0 application that uses the camera, showing the preview and allowing the user to take a photo. I'm using the CameraCaptureDialog component and I wanted to draw a rectangle on the preview screen, but I wasn't able to do it... Any ideas?
Do you think the Overlay mixer filter in DirectShow can be useful? If so, do you have any example? (The problem is I work on the CF 2.0, so many solutions that work ok for the normal framework here don't work...).
Thanks in advance,

Giacomo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for samples showing VMR Mixer Bitmap capability and mixing presented video with custom overlay

- [Drawing video with text on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270809/drawing-video-with-text-on-top)
- [Drawing on top of DirectShow - desperate](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/4ac26a78-9709-470d-8896-08e928c3d9fb)
- [Displaying an Application-Supplied Bitmap on the Composited Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the VMR Mixer Bitmap doesn't seem to work in the Compact Framework.
Looking around I found something about the "Sample Grabber", do you know if it can be used?

Comment: Yes you can. With `Sample Grabber` you get video frames coming through pipeline. If you initialize `Sample Grabber` to 24/32 bit RGB format, you will be having video frames in this format coming before they are shown on the screen. You can update this data in-place and put your overlays onto the picture.